Is it possible to infer the type of a value inside a class instance when using a function to grab it?
I'm wondering if it's possible to write a function that retains typing and is the equivalent of this:
class Example {
    someNumber:number = 1;
    someString:string = "test";
}

const example = new Example();
const value = example.someNumber; // type = number

I would like to be able to type this kind of function:
function getValueFromInstance<T>( target:T, key:keyof T ) {
    return target[ key ];
}

const value = getValueFromInstance( example, "someNumber" ); // type = string | number

TypeScript already recognizes that the possible result can only be a string or a number here, but can I somehow push it a step further to have it distinguish between the two? Especially if "someNumber" is a fixed value in the code and not coming from a variable?

https://tsplay.dev/wReY7W?

You don't get the correct corresponding value type of the class member's key because you index T with keyof T. That will always return a union of all all possible value types.
Instead, use another generic parameter with a constraint to infer one specific keyof T in order to index one value type.
class Example {
  someNumber: number = 1;
  someString: string = "test";
}

declare const example: Example;

function getValueFromInstance<T, K extends keyof T>(target: T, key: K) {
  return target[key];
}

const value = getValueFromInstance(example, "someNumber");
//    ^? const value: number

TypeScript Playground
